# Highcharts, build a "Text" graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to build my charts that shows the values that comes from a sensor placed into my garage: all of these values are numeric values, so, i have no problem to build a graph like the following one [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q60ytzxh/)

As i've said, all of the values that comes from the sensor are numeric, except one: the "status", this value is a string value type and it's not a fixed string, it can be:

- Transmitting
- Standby
- Active
- Alarm
- Or any free string

So, my intention is - and i don't know if that can be feasible - to draw a graph with a fixed serie value (e.g.: 1...maybe i have to use a javascript function that maps the "status" to a given value?) and show that string as fixed datalabels as shown in the fiddle that i've posted.

*Final Remarks:*

The data that comes from the sensor is a time-series value, like the following:

```
{"datetime": 1566730095, "status": "transmitting"}
{"datetime": 1566730162, "status": "hello! i'm here"}
```

This chart will be a separate chart instead the numeric charts, in order to simplify the build and management.

The final goal can be something like that (the following graph is a pure graphical example): 
[image: Image example of the expected result graph]

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n0rt1jys/. That's what you need?

Comment: This is exactly what i need man! in addition, i want to export this text data into CSV format using the default export.js module of highcharts, there is possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/to92mbu0/. Can I add this as an answer and you will accept it?

Comment: The only thing that i see is that export method will override all graphs, in my app i have normal numeric charts and string charts and this solution will broke the export of numeric charts.

Comment: So what do you need exactly? I showed you only an example that it is possible and how to change the exported rows.

Comment: The export function goal is to have a single function definition that can manage multiple charts, please note that the export can be something like that (in case of numeric, multi serie numeric chart): https://imgur.com/9xGD0kB
Your function works, but seems statically bounded to this current graph structure

Comment: Sorry @WojciechChmiel, i've tested better your export code and i've noticed that works well adding a ternary operator as following: row[1] = (row.name === undefined ? row[1] : row.name);

Now works good, please answer to my question, i'll accept that!
Many thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve it you can map data like that:

```
series: [{
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    format: '{point.name}',
    rotation: -45,
    align: 'left',
    y: -8
  },
  data: data.map(item => {
    return {
      x: item.datetime,
      y: 1,
      name: item.status
    };
  })
}]
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/840tv6mz/

---

To change the way data is exported to CSV you can use this wrapper (edit it as needed):

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'getDataRows', function(proceed, multiLevelHeaders) {
    var rows = proceed.call(this, multiLevelHeaders);

    rows[0][0] = 'Time';
    rows[0][1] = 'Status';

    rows = rows.map(row => {
      if (row.x) {
        row[0] = H.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S.%L', row.x);
        row[1] = row.name;
      }
      return row;
    });

    return rows;
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/to92mbu0/